# How can I get the windows console window to span multiple monitors?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, powershell, cmd.exe

Is there a way to make the windows commandline span multiple monitors?

I'm trying to view a console application that I've written, but it's output is too large for the default window size, I've tried decreasing the fonts and increasing buffers and layouts, and also tried console2, but no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the console as large as I'd like.

I'm streaming video to the console in the form of numbers, so I can't have it wrapping the text.

I'm using windows 10

Comment: I'll let it redirect you, but short answer, no, it can't be done

Comment: Take a different approach. Writ your content to a file and use Get-Content leveraging the -tail and -wait params that you can view output real time via Out-GridView (which you can stretch across multiple screens). Of course , this is assuming that your output are string single line strings, or write a simple Winform/WPF GUI with a text box, that you can send that data to (which you can stretch across multiple screens).

Comment: I guess I did tag this as powershell, but I'm actually running this in python, I don't know anything about powershell, I was born and raised on cmd

Comment: OK, then you want to delete that tag so as not to confuse folks. PowerShell is cmd on steroids and more. BTW, of course you can build GUI with Python, and you can use python with PowerShell. for Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676403/running-python-in-powershell

Comment: It still applies, to both cmd and powershell, because it's not specific to any kind of terminal, just windows terminals in general.